# Why icon don't appear on Android Galaxy S6 and S7?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a problem without logic, my application run smoothly on almost all devices but when I try the Samsung Galaxy S6 and S7 models, simply icon does not appear anywhere.

I've tried to send the official store (still the same)
If I run via simulator the application opens, but without the icon (shortcut).

My AndroidManifest.xml

```
[...]
<application
    android:name="MyApp"
    android:label="MyApp"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_phone"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true">

    <activity android:name=".MyAppTalk"
        android:label="MyApp"
        android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_phone"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustNothing">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/phone" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/person" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            <data android:scheme="voicemail" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />


        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            <data android:scheme="tel" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/calls" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_BUTTON" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- This was never intended to be public, but is here for backward
             compatibility.  Use Intent.ACTION_DIAL instead. -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.phone.action.TOUCH_DIALER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.TAB" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/recentCallsIconLabel">
            <action android:name="com.android.phone.action.RECENT_CALLS" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.TAB" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.android.keyguard.layout"
            android:resource="@layout/keyguard_preview" />
    </activity>

[...]
```

I added several "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" as despair,

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the appropriate resolution for those devices in your mipmap folder?

Comment: Yes, hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi and xxxhdpi @ChrisStillwell

Comment: Try a different pic with higher resolution. And consider running on other high resolution devices as well

Comment: Already tried to images with higher resolution, I have not tried to emulate devices supporting higher resolutions (I'll try) @7geeky